# Wpf User control not showing up after run my App

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm dealing with WPF App where I have to implement User Control and include it in my project. I did it, and it is showing properly in Designer view, but when I run it, it's not showing up.

Code for User control:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="facebook.showPost"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Label FontSize="20" Content="My label" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window tag in Main Window form:

```
<Window x:Class="facebook.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:facebook"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        MinWidth="400"
        Background="#dfe3ee"
        Closing="On_exit"
        Title="facebook" Height="450" Width="800">
```

And this is how I call the User Control in my Main Form:

```
<TabItem Header="New Item" >
    <local:showPost />
</TabItem>
```

In the designer, everything is okay, but after running, all window is blank.

Comment: Shouldn't the tabitem be inside a tabcontrol? That or show the actual xaml rather than bits and snips.

Answer (score 2):

I found the error. In the constructor I forgot to call InitializeComponent() method. It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks! I had also forgot it, this saved me som headache :)

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that I had this same issue. Thanks!